# Issue with font-size 62.5%

Tags: css, css-rem

I have a very strange issue. Sometimes my `/` page displays the website normal, but sometimes zoomed. And the "funny" thing is, that only the startpage is affected.

Above you can see the "funny" one, and below it when the page loads normal:

[image]

So when i get the "funny" site, I only have to resize the windows and it looks normal again.

**Appears in Chrome 43**

Comment: give some more data, like a link to the site, if you made it yourself or some more info about when it happens

Comment: I have experienced this in Chrome using REMs as well. I suspect it is a Chrome bug.

Comment: It's not accessible from extern. I can only show you images or give more information about it. When you reload the startpage a few times, I would guess it appears like 30%.

Comment: did you made it yourself ir is some sort of environment?

Comment: I still don't know 62.5% of what. Can you make a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) or something?